# Prove that $\{x \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times : x^4 = 1\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ of order four.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime such that $4\mid p−1$. How do I prove that $\{x \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times : x^4 = 1\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of  $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ of order four?

I know that if $p$ is prime then $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $p−1$ and I have also shown that $|g^k|=\frac{|g|}{\gcd(k,|g|)}$ but I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: What do you know about $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$? It being a cyclic group might help.

Comment: By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), or its proof applied to $p-1$, there is $x\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ such that $x^2=p-1$. Then $x,x^2=p-1, x^3=p-x, x^4=1$ are the solutions of $x^4=1$, which cannot have more solutions since $p$ is prime.